# Delayed onBlur callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm making an `Autocomplete` component in React which shows a dropdown of suggested completions as you type into a text box. Clicking on a suggestion should fire a callback, and the dropdown should disappear when the text box loses focus. The problem is that the `onBlur` event for the text box fires *before* the `onClick` event for the the suggestion, so what happens is:

1. Click on item
2. Text box loses focus => `this.setState(this.getInitialState())`
3. Component rerenders, with no suggestions box because state has been cleared
4. The click event lands on the empty space where the suggestion item used to be

What's the best way to solve this without resorting to a hack like `onBlur={() => setTimeout(() => this.setState(this.getInitialState()), 100)}`?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Found a very simple solution: the `mousedown` event fires for the result item being clicked before `blur` fires for the text input. Furthermore if the `mousedown` callback calls `event.preventDefault()`, it prevents the `blur` event from firing for the input, but doesn't prevent the future `click` event from firing on the result item once `mouseup` occurs. So, long story short, simply adding this handler to the result item fixes everything: `onMouseDown={event => event.preventDefault()}`

Answer (score 2):

Looks like there's an open source `Autocomplete` component and they had to tackle [this exact problem](https://github.com/reactjs/react-autocomplete/blob/2982800564c35f7e31e2410d9ddef03608ea3786/lib/Autocomplete.js#L276).

Comment: Probably best to copy/paste a portion of that code in here since the content of that link could change.

Comment: @jacob changed link to an exact commit hash.